# Django- Creating a log for any changes in any model data i.e creation, updation and deletion?

Tags: django, django-models

So i have been given a task to create a Activity Log page which shows the changes that have happened to any model data i.e either it is created or updated or deleted.

My solution is to create a Activity model and store the changes following way-

1- override the save method and delete method and then save in Activity model or

2- use signals and then save it the Activity model.

the Activity model right now contains only these fields-

performed_on,

performed_by,

type_of_operation- Creation, Updation, Deletion

Is there any other better way to achieve this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take look at https://github.com/jjkester/django-auditlog for logging model changes. Maybe use the app are get ideas on how to do it yourself. I have used it for history tracking and seems to work fine.

Comment: I will definitely try it.. Thank you